# javascript: send myself message when a user press button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm looking for a way to send myself a message(email) when a user submit a form on my website.
Is there any service for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a service that can do this.  https://formspree.io/  You setup your form action to point to their url with your email address appended to the end.

Comment: exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call a server side file (where you should write your email trigger logic) in your `<form>` tag's "action" attribute with it's "method" attribute is set to "post"

Alternately you may also try this too,

```
<form action="mailto:emailaddress@domain.tld" method="GET">
   <input name="subjectText" type="text" />
   <textarea name="message"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: By "server side file", you mean PHP?

Comment: Please check my recent edit. PHP is one among the option.